# How to test thread-safety with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, thread-safety

Recently my current Rails project had a lot of problems, because there was not-threadsafe code inside one of my models. Is there a way to test thread-safety with Rails 3 apps, like running multiple pow instances on my computer?

Comment: Ok the problem is defenitly `serialize`, which seems not to be thread-safe. I will write a test-app to proof my statement.

Answer (score 0):

Mimic the way your production server is setup and use ab testing.